# Add Javascript Method

Tags: javascript

Is there way to create a new global method where I can have variable.myMethod() and it return true or false? Basically, I want to check to see if the variable is undefined and instead of using `typeof(variable) == 'undefined'` or specifying a function, is it possible to do something like variable.isUndefined() and it would return true or false?

Comment: Undefined or undeclared? Why not `isUndefined(variable)`?

Comment: `if(!variable) { ... }`?...

Comment: No, you can't do this. Methods are properties of objects, not variables.

Comment: Be careful with the terms that you use here. Undeclared and undefined mean two very different things. For example, if the variable is **undeclared**, then there literally is nothing. If the variable is **undefined**, the variable is there, but it hasn't been assigned a value.

Comment: If `variable` is `undefined` then how would you be able to call a function on it?

Comment: @Barmar, variables in JavaScript *are* objects, are they not?

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld No, a variable may contain a reference to an object. But before it's assigned, it doesn't contain a reference to anything. So `variable.myMethod()` will complain that `undefined` doesn't have a `myMethod` property.

Comment: @Barmar, that's correct. My mistake. I touched on this a bit more in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer, so I can go into a bit more detail.

As I mentioned in my comment, you have to be **extremely** careful about the terms that you use here, as undeclared and undefined mean two very different things.

If a variable is "**undeclared**", it doesn't exist, thus you cannot attempt to call any methods that might exist on it if it were declared.

If a variable is "**undefined**", it exists, but it doesn't have a value assigned to it. When this is the case, you *can* attempt to call methods that may exist on it, however the chances are that they'll fail, since variable doesn't have any value.

Every type in JavaScript is a child of the `Object` type, therefore you add a method to them, like follows:

```
Object.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    console.log("This is my method");
};
```

So, in theory, you could create a method to check to see if a value exists, and return a `true`/`false` value.

Similarly to what StackOverflow user [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out, `undefined` and `null` are not children of the `Object` type, thus your method will not exist.

As other comments have stated, you're probably better of sticking with something like follows:

```
if (!myVariable) {
    // myVariable doesn't have a value
}
```

I'd like to point out that most of my explanation was unnecessary, as user [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out, ***there is no practical difference between undeclared and undefined***.

If a variable is undeclared, it's "value" is essentially read as `undefined`, thus your method will not exist.

Comment: The question never used the term "undeclared", just "undefined". What is that part of your answer referring to?

Comment: Unless you're in strict mode, the difference between undeclared and undefined is not very significant. Assigning to the variable will create a global variable by that name, and reading from it will return `undefined`, just like a declared variable that hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: @Barmar, you are correct again. The original question never mentioned "undeclared", however, I feel it is worth noting the different between those terms. Even when not in strict mode, attempting to call a method on a variable that does not exist, will result in failure, agreed?

Comment: That's correct, but that happens because reading it returns `undefined`, just like a variable that does exist but hasn't been assigned yet. So there's no practical difference between undeclared and undefined.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Great point. Will edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score -1):

this is a paradox. you can never have a method inside an undefined object because and undefined object does not have anything at all. to make it clear imagine this object

```
var a = {};
```

a.b is undefined here, so trying to call a.b.isDefined() can not work because you dont even have b. to make it work you need b defined like this

```
var a = {b:1,isUndefined:function(){return false}}
```

so you have to make a generic function that takes objects. This will do the trick

```
function isUndefined(obj,stringLink){
 var arrayLink = stringLink.split(".");
 var current = obj[arrayLink[0]];
 if(!current)return false;
 for(var i =1;i< arrayLink.length;i++){
   current = current[arrayLink[i]];
   if (!current)return false;
  }
return true;
}
```

it will more or less check for nested object until it reach the target.
if you have

```
var a = {b:{c:{d:{e:{f:1}}}}}
//this function will do a["b"]["c"]["d"]["e"]["f"]
isUndefined(a,"a.b.c.d.e.f") //gives true
//or you can use 
if(a&&a.b&&a.b.c&&a.b.c.d&&a.b.c.d.e&&a.b.c.d.e.f)//lots of work here
```

Comment: sorry here it should return true instead of false, and false instead of true.. or jsut rename the function to isDefined.